# Pseudo-manifolds and homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff

Is there a good reference for the proof that the cobordism group of pseudo-manifolds is isomorphic to the singular homology group?

I was looking for a more geometrical definition of homology and found [these notes](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~cohen/courses/PastSemesters/SPRING09/M7512/MacPherson.pdf) that give a more geometrical definition of homology and I also found an [entry](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Steenrod_problem) in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics that gave a reference for the proof of the result above. However, I would want to know if there is a more modern and easy to read reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be aware of the book "A geometric approach to homology theory" by Buoncristiano, Rourke and Sanderson.  However, I am not willing to claim that it is modern (1976) or easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

For a modern textbook reference, you could try [On Thom Spectra, Orientability and Cobordism](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/On_Thom_Spectra_Orientability_and_Cobord.html?id=JYk0GKTNlBIC) by Yuli Rudyak. The result you mention is in Chapter VIII.

You may also be interested in the presentation of singular (co)homology as (co)bordism of [stratifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratifold), due to Matthias Kreck. His textbook [Differential Algebraic Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821848984) is extremely well-written, and reads like a textbook for an alternative first course on homology theory.

Both of these books can be found online without too much effort.